# How to correctly read a file (csv or txt) and print its content in JavaScript/Html?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, txt

My problem is the following:

My company asked me to modify a dashboard in order to print the update date on the dashboard. Currently the update date is saved in a .csv and this file is load in the *init.py* file, the file that launches the dashboard.

I need to load this *date_data.csv* directly in the HTML template in order to keep the update date updated without launching the *init.py* file everyday.

When I am searching for "reading a .txt or a .csv file in JavaScript and print it", I only find how to create a button that allow the user to load the file himself.

I would like to directly :

- load the file with javascript (the *date_data.csv*), may be in a string variable.
- print this string in HTML

It seems very simple but i didn't find a way to do achieve this.

```
<div style="color : white"; align="right"> Most recent update : date </div>
```

I only need to replace the 'date' in the above code by the date present in my file *date_data.csv*.

Currently my csv looks like this :

```
;date
0;2020-11-09
```

I can transform it if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to request the CSV whenever you load the page. After the request you can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the text (via [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp))  by the newline character (`\n`) to get all the rows. Then you can split each row in cells by using the correct delimiter.

All that is left is to get the cell that contains the date and place that value inside your `div` element.

*I used an open dataset as example. Update the `CSV_DELIMITER` and `CSV_URL` to your needs*

```js
const CSV_DELIMITER = ",";
const CSV_URL = "https://data.bloomington.in.gov/dataset/ff8cb100-017d-44ef-a05a-37a19ec44611/resource/521fc11c-c18e-417a-b996-a383854805b4/download/2016-first-quarter-stolen-guns.csv";

const getCSV = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return await response.text();
  }catch(error) {
    // Error handling
    console.error(error);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const dateOutput = document.querySelector("#recent-update");

  const csv = await getCSV(CSV_URL);
  const rows = csv.split(/\n/g);
  const cells = rows.map((row) => row.split(CSV_DELIMITER));
  
  console.log(cells);
  
  const date = cells[1][1];
  
  dateOutput.textContent = `Most recent update : ${date}`;
});
```

```css
.as-console.wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<div id="recent-update">Most recent update : date</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly !! Thanks a lot :)